# Behavior of C++'s std::discrete_distribution vs. sample() in R

Tags: c++, random, statistics, std, distribution

I want to draw a number from a set of frequencies until all values are zero. By drawing the frequencies of the remaining numbers is decreasing.  In R there is a "simple" function sample to do that for me. In C++ I found the std::discrete_distribution but not very much detail information about it

1. I can't find a clear descrition of the algorithm of R and / or the std::discrete_distribution to compare the functionality. Is the behavior the same? Can I solve my task with this C++ STDL?
2. As I programmed other PRNG's non STDL - Which functionaltyof them is needed so they can be used together with std::discrete_distribution - cppreference and other sites/forums are there very silent to this
3. On a second place in my code I need a similar behavior ( fixed frequencies for each draw ) I found nowhere a explicit extra invokation nor parameter to seperate both functionalities. DO I need to create a new instance with lowered parameters?! This is obviousliy a thing I can't belive...

actually I'm summing the frequencies (hold by a std::vector) up until random number is smaller or equal. As this is:

- ineffective in time / ressources
- I'm not really sure if this is statistically allowed

I hope to find a better solution with you help.

THANK YOU for your time, support and answers of course :)

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do?  I'm not at all sure I understand your question as it currently stands.  If I am understanding, I'm wondering why you don't just shuffle and then iterate through the shuffled set.

Comment: Did You check this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution ? What is it missing for You?

Comment: This is what (draft) standard says about this function: http://eel.is/c++draft/rand.dist.samp.discrete

Comment: Regarding point 2, cppreference page on discrete_distribution's operator() says what the RNG must do (with a clickable link)

Comment: Hello, for sure!;) for the first case (drawing without putting back) this is an option - turning to which algorithm it's shuffled the results may be not as good as by drawing from randomness.
For the second case drawing with putting back from probabilities  there is no other chance ( as far as I know ) as drawing from a distribution.
The main questions regard to functionality of std::discrete_distribution - e.g. with functionality is called inside from Prng so what is mandatory for my Prng's.
How does this thing work? I tried to reed in stdl but what is more than cryptic for my knowledge

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk yes exactly this part I read ... but which function from PRNG will be called ? How can I modify the paramter set after each call? For sure it's a good starting point but I need more information

Comment: I think if You add a simple program in R with input and output, which is mentioned, then it would help to produce an equivalent program in C++.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sample.html

Comment: Which C++ compiler and version do You want to use?

Answer (score 0):

C++17 gives us the [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string in = "abcdefgh";
    std::string out;

    std::sample(in.begin(), in.end(), 
                std::back_inserter(out),
                5,
                std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()} //(*)
                );

    std::cout << "five random letters out of " << in << " : " << out << '\n';
}
```

If You don't have C++17, then proposal [A sample Proposal, v4](https://wg21.link/n3925) contains a sample implementation (using uniform_int_distribution):

```
// the primary function, which calls the detailed functions depending on types of iterators in the used containers.
template< class PopIter, class SampleIter, class Size, class URNG >
SampleIter sample( PopIter first, PopIter last, SampleIter out, Size n, URNG&& g )
{
    using pop_t  = typename std::iterator_traits< PopIter >::iterator_category;
    using samp_t = typename std::iterator_traits< SampleIter >::iterator_category;
    return __sample( first, last, pop_t{}, out, samp_t{}, n, forward< URNG >( g ) );
}

template< class PopIter, class SampleIter, class Size, class URNG >
SampleIter __sample( PopIter first,
                     PopIter last,
                     std::input_iterator_tag,
                     SampleIter out,
                     std::random_access_iterator_tag,
                     Size   n,
                     URNG&& g )
{
    using dist_t  = std::uniform_int_distribution< Size >;
    using param_t = typename dist_t::param_type;
    dist_t d{};
    Size   sample_sz{0};
    while ( first != last && sample_sz != n )
        out[ sample_sz++ ] = *first++;
    for ( Size pop_sz{sample_sz}; first != last; ++first, ++pop_sz )
    {
        param_t const p{0, pop_sz};
        Size const    k{d( g, p )};
        if ( k < n )
            out[ k ] = *first;
    }
    return out + sample_sz;
}

template< class PopIter, class SampleIter, class Size, class URNG >
SampleIter __sample( PopIter first,
                     PopIter last,
                     std::forward_iterator_tag,
                     SampleIter out,
                     std::output_iterator_tag,
                     Size   n,
                     URNG&& g )
{
    using dist_t  = std::uniform_int_distribution< Size >;
    using param_t = typename dist_t::param_type;
    dist_t d{};
    Size   unsampled_sz = std::distance( first, last );
    for ( n = min( n, unsampled_sz ); n != 0; ++first )
    {
        param_t const p{0, --unsampled_sz};
        if ( d( g, p ) < n )
        {
            *out++ = *first;
            --n;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: @prometheus Do you understand this?